# What value does the continued fraction $[1,2,3,1,2,3,...]$ represent?

Tags: continued-fractions, constants

I have found a number that satisfies this continued fraction:$$n=1+{1\over{2+{1\over{3+{1\over n}}}}}$$ With a value of about $1.4403$ after 9 layers of nesting. I've tried googling it and plugging it into *Wolfram Alpha*, but it doesn't seem to be used. Does it have any application or is some root of another number?

**ADDENDUM**

It has the exact value of $${13\pm(\sqrt{37}+\frac{1}{7}})\over{7}$$

Comment: You have a $\frac{1}{n}$ in your fraction, should this be $\ldots$ instead?

Comment: @gd1035 I prefer writing my continued fractions in a way that allows them to be solved algebraically, hence that notation.

Comment: @Blue ahhh the number was in an image format rather than text, so it wasn't indexed by my search engine.

Comment: @user189728 Regarding notation, you could write it $[1;2,3,\ldots,k,\ldots]$. Either way, note that you've assigned $n$ already on the left-hand side, so it would be best not to use it again for a different purpose on the right.

Comment: @Théophile the $n$ on the right is equal to the one on the left

Comment: @user189728 Oh, I see, I thought that $n$ was an index. There is often a convention that the letters $m,n$, etc., represent integers, while $x,y$, etc., represent real numbers, which is why I was confused. In any case, it is clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OEIS sequence A060997](http://oeis.org/A060997) is the decimal expansion of the  continued fraction $\,1+1/(2+1/3(1+1/4+\dots)))\,$ with value  $1.433127426722311758317183455775\dots$ and the exact formula is $\,I_0(2)/I_1(2)\,$ where $\,I_n(x)\,$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

For the continued fraction $\,1+1/(2+1/(3+1/(1+1/(2+1/3+\dots))))) ,\,$ solving the equation $\, x =1+1/(2+1/(3+1/x)) \,$ simplifies to the  quadratic equation $\, 0 = 7x^2 - 8x - 3 \,$ with solution $\, x = (4 + \sqrt{37})/7 \approx  1.440394647185.\,$ The decimal expansion is the [sequence A177036](http://oeis.org/A177036) whose continued fraction is [sequence A010882](http://oeis.org/A010882).

Comment: This result is for the continued fraction $[1,2,3,4,5,6...]$, not the continued fraction $[1,2,3,1,2,3,...]$

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The original title perhaps misleadingly wrote the continued fraction as $[1, 2, 3, \ldots]$ suggested the former (though the text specified the latter).

Comment: Shouldn't the equation read  $x=1+1/(2+1/(3+1/x))$ rather than $ x=1+1/(2+1/(3+x))$...?

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, my typo is fixed now. Thanks.